# is it possible to generate data model class or structure dynamically ?? in entity framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dynamic-data

currently my WPF application is using entity framework (code first) and i got stuck on a new feature in my project. in this new feature, i need to create tables in MS SQL Server DB  on runtime. these tables will contain random number of columns and they can updated later too.

> i am confused on how the data model class will be generated on runtime
> (of new tables created in DB)?
>
> and how will i use them in my code too
> ?

one solution comes up in my mind (i haven't implemented yet)

i should create a new table name "TableNamesandFields" and it will contain new table and column names in it. by using "TableNamesandFields" table i will maintain new table structure.

by using data from "TableNamesandFields" i could create temporary data model of new tables (currently i don't know any way of doing it) and use them in my views

if anyone implemented and handled situation like this please help me out in it

Comment: May I ask what the use-case scenario is for dynamically generating tables at runtime?  This *hints* (I could be wrong of course) at a design issue.

Comment: @Moo-Juice use-case scenario: any user in application can create some document template (DT1) like billing invoice etc. user will add certain set of field of invoice (than new table will be created with the fields). DT1 can be used for maintaining list of invoices. 
(I've been told that)previously it was maintained in single table (containing all document templates) and because of it query result time was too high ...

Comment: `I need to create tables in MS SQL Server DB on runtime` - That's not what O/RMs are for. That said, with Entity Framework Code First you can actually do that by incorporating additional entities and mapping them via `OnModelCreating()`, you will have to use `Migrations`. That said, there are much better approaches for this, such as storing the Document Template in XML in a single `DocumentTemplate` table, and then storing indiviual field values in a second table `DocumentFields`, for example.

Comment: @HighCore i will look into your suggested approach for solving my problem

Comment: I'd suggest not to force EF to *somehow* manage to do that but to revisit your use of EF altogether. EF is not aimed in the direction you're taking and your design approach in the first place. Reading your comments shows your idea to be pretty much dead wrong - make a new table for each new template is probably the WORST way of doing it. How many rows are you talking about? just yesterday I was toying with a large(ish) table (900000 rows) and querying with a self join takes 0.02s or less, which makes me think your table isn't properly indexed to see "too high" query times

Answer (score -4):

WPF4.0 provided ability to databind to dynamic (runtime generated) properties using the DynamicObject,basically, you should inherit DynamicObject (maybe impl INotifyPropertyChanged Interface also), override TryGetMember and TrySetMember method.

I am not familiar with this stuff, so i recommend you take a look at this post(http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2011/05/data-binding-improvements-in-wpf-40.html)
or use key word "**WPF DynamicObject DataBinding**" and ask google.

**just one thing,for your case, you may need a dictionary to maintain dynamic properties(above post use public filed "MyName").

Comment: -1 this has nothing to do with what the OP is asking

Comment: @HighCore Actually this could be useful because the OP wants to "create temporary data model ... and use them in my views". If the binding field names are only known at runtime then this is an option (another option is to bind to a dictionary using square bracket notation). But of course the whole situation should be avoided in the first place...